# Выполнение запроса по условию

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Почему в браузер ничего не выводиться?

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
$num=5;
$result=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM gb");
$chislo=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($chislo>$num) {
    while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {     
        echo ''.$res['name'].'<br>'.$res['message'].'<hr>'; 
    }
    echo '<a href=?pages=1>Вперед</a>';
}
?>
```

Подключение к БД есть, если не ставить if, то всё работает, а в нём нет. Почему?

Comment: Вам надо, чтоб вытянутых записей из БД было больше пяти? Тогда:

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > $num) {
       /* и т.д. */
    }

Comment: Классно переменные названы ^_^

Comment: Угу )) Гоавное никогда не запутаешься между $result и $res, $chislo и $num ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно число строк меньше 5 или равно пяти и условие не выполняется?

Comment: спс,да,совсем забыл про это)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте включить отображение ошибок если выключены, посмотрите на какой строке падает.

```
<?php 
 error_reporting(E_ALL); 
 ini_set("display_errors", 1); 
?>
```

Comment: Ни на какой. Код выполняется успешно, только без вывода в браузер из-за неправильной логики программы.